# JFrog / Artifactory plugin for file download in Gradle

Tags: plugins, download, build.gradle, artifactory

I know there are external plugins like the one in the link: https://www.michel-kraemer.com/gradle-download-task-download-files-with-progress/ for downloading files through Gradle. But since I have to download the files from Artifactory, I was wondering if there are any JFrog/Artifactory plugins to download files from Artifactory in Gradle. Can anyone please provide code also?

Answer (score 0):

JFrog has a Gradle plugin, with examples available on [Github](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples).
You can find additional documentation in [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) Jfrog wiki page.

HTH,
Or

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have already gone through these, but couldn't find much help. Also, I am very new to gradle. Hence, it will be great, if you can please provide a detailed solution, possibly with some code.

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere in the gradle plugin page which details how to perform the equivalent of `jfrog rt download` from within gradle using the artifactory plugin for gradle.

Comment: @fquinner you need to declare whatever you need to download as a Gradle dependency, then Gradle will download it for you.

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch, it doesn't really explain how to do what is asked though. The file I'm looking to download is not a gradle dependency it's boilerplate common build scripts reused across many applications. Its contents will actually be called within gradle itself. Can you use gradle to download individual files from artifactory with the artifactory plugin?

Comment: That's really a Gradle question, that's why none of us got into the details in this question. Maybe a question phrased like "How do I download an arbitrary file using Gradle" would be a better place to discuss it. Long story short, if you need this file during your build, it is a dependency, and should be declared as such.