# Sharing of Credentials between JFrog CLI and Gradle

Tags: artifactory

Is there an option to allow the Artifactory plugin for gradle to inherit authentication from JFrog CLI's configuration file?

When you call `jfrog rt config`, it creates a configuration file including your credentials in `~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf`. If I then try to use the gradle artifactory plugin, it seems to ignore this file, and I have to provide username and password directly to the build system **as well**.

Just feels weird having to provide a username / password combination to the build system when I have already authenticated against the server using a JFrog tool locally.

Comment: are you calling Gradle with JFrog CLI? Using `jfrog rt gradlec`?

Comment: No this is using vanilla gradle with the artifactory plugin. Realistically I'd prefer to use the gradle artifactory plugin for everything if possible (remove the jfrog dependency entirely), but I couldn't see an option to download a file from artifactory using that plugin which is the only reason I was using jfrog at all (I commented earlier on in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623375/jfrog-artifactory-plugin-for-file-download-in-gradle too).

Comment: Added a comment there on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you run JFrog CLI and Gradle as separate tasks and processes, they won't share credentials.

Instead, try running your Gradle [using JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenandGradleBuilds) (`jfrog rt gradlec`), it will do exactly what you expect.